# Why this code is consuming memory and it is not get fully reclaimed? 

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, xmlhttprequest

I has a simple JavaScript code which is consuming memory while running infinitely. Memory consumption is monitored by Google Chrome internal memory profiler.

```
  setInterval(function(){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', 'json.txt', true);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           console.log(this.responseText);
        }
     };
     xhr.send('');
  }, 500);
```

Html file with above code sample and `json.txt` is hosted on on my local server, getting a file isn't taking more than 500ms (it is always about 7-10ms).

In a long time run the memory graph is looks like that
[image: Initial memory consumption graph]

**EDIT** The same Chrome window after a hour of work
[image: Graph after a hour of work]

**EDIT**
On the long run (hours) not all memory is reclaimed an graph is still ascending.
I understand **why** the memory is consumed, i didn't understand why it is **not fully reclaimed**.

**EDIT**
This is how i can reduce memory leak

```
  var callback = function(){
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          console.log(this.responseText);
      }
  } 

  setInterval(function(){
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', 'json.txt', true);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = callback;
     xhr.send('');
  }, 500);
```

This improvement allowing not to link callback's closure to `xhr` var.

Comment: were you able to fix your leak with the accepted answer?

Comment: @brainjam, the accpeted answer gives me the clue, how this code can be improved. See my edit.

Comment: my brain hurts. I guess your original construction was creating a circular reference between the anonymous function and the closure. This is a very good example of a very subtle (to me anyways) memory leak pattern. Thanks for persisting until you got a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine this interval isn't being set in a vacuum. The the function you're passing into setInterval may have access to the lexical scope it was defined in. This means every variable around it will always be reachable in the garbage collector's eyes, even if you're not using those variables within the function. The garbage collector will never clean it up. It might be better to define the function in a more sanitary environment where it wont have closure access to any variables large in size.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I'll try to make myself more clear. This has nothing to do with the XHR - you could put anything (or even nothing) in that setInterval function and it would still leak if there's some variables in its lexical scope that you would want cleaned up. You just need to make sure the setInterval function doesn't have closure access to any variables you want cleaned up. For example:

```
(function() {
  var a = readFile('a-very-big-file.txt');

  setInterval(function() {
    console.log('im leaking!');
  }, 500);
})();
```

That will leak. Even though the setInterval doesn't do anything particularly meaningful, it still has access to "a", and the garbage collector sees it as reachable.

Comment: Ok, the function which is in setInterval is having access to at least global `window` object. But it is declared once and must not to infinite consume memory. Well, each time the function is called, new XHR object is created (let's name it A) and new function (B) are set to one of it's properties. Now fn B seeing object A. But these object are NOT reacheable from any other scope and thus must be garbage collected as far as i understand GC's work.

Comment: This must not "incrementally" leak. No new objects created in loop here.

Answer (score 6):

For one you repeatedly load the content of `json.txt`, which will need some memory. Apart from that the XHR itself might need some memory as well. I don't see it as much of a problem, however, since the memory seems to get reclaimed anyway.

Comment: On a long run i can see on the graph, what not all memory is reclaimed.

Comment: Edited my question. Added another graph of the same Chrome window after a hour of work.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't it? At least
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
must consume memory on each iteration and collected by GC (probably, it's seen on your chart).

Comment: Added another chart. It can be seen there what not all memory is reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

If the request-response cycle takes longer than the specified interval there certainly will be some memory overhead.

Since memory will be freed only after a request has completed(Success or Error).

Answer (score 0):

The memory is not being fully reclaimed most likely due to the use of console.log. I assume that under the hood, console will add things to the internal array, or maybe a string, and since you are adding large chunks of data to it, and never remove from it, GC will never clean it up, while the application is running. Try commenting out that statement and see if it changes memory usage. Memory that is used for creating XMLHttpRequest is eventually freed by GC, since the reference to it will become orphaned after the request is complete, but console is a global variable, that still stays in the scope while the page is available.

Comment: No, this is not the reason. I've deleted `console.log(...)` statement and it still consuming memory. In half of an hour memory consumed by Google Chrome tab (according to `about:memory`, Private memory parameter) is ascending from 6288Kb to 22304Kb

Comment: I faced the same situation in node.. Console.log consumes memory.. but its freed after some time..